# webkit-animation issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, webkit

Since two or three weeks my Chrome 43 does not show my CSS animation. I changed nothing, it happend in one second without any code changes.

```
@-moz-keyframes animaciya {   
  from {background-color: #EF7877;}  
  to {background-color: #dddd00;} 
}

@-ms-keyframes animaciya {
  from {background-color: #EF7877;}
  to {background-color: #dddd00;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes animaciya {
  from { background-color: #EF7877; }
  to { background-color: #dddd00; }
}

.attention {
  -moz-animation: animaciya 0.5s ease-in-out 1s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: animaciya 0.5s ease-in-out 1s infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: animaciya 0.5s ease-in-out 1s infinite alternate;
}
```

I found many posts about it from 2012 or 2014, but in my case it happend few weeks ago. I also found that my Sencha Touch app doesn't scroll on Chrome either, because of `webkit-transform: translate3d()`.

Is it a new bug?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 43 doesn't need vendor prefix for animation, so you must add at the end:

```
@keyframes animaciya {
  from { background: #EF7877; }
  to { background: #dddd00; }
}
```

and then add at the bottom:

```
animation: animaciya 0.5s ease-in-out 1s infinite alternate;
```

More info: http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20animation

Pen: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/JdbeJe

Comment: unfortunately didn't help((

Comment: did you add the second line?

Comment: Could you give me a pen?

Comment: are you sure? because it works for me on chrome 43: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/JdbeJe

Comment: thats interesting, because it works in the pen, but not on my page. However it worked on the page in stopped suddenly without code changes. Magic.... I don't understand

Comment: ok, the point was -- the animation gets covered by another class having background-color. But ist still interesting why it happend suddenly, and why it still works in other browsers

Comment: suddenly only once or more than once?

Comment: more than once. I have an element with a class where background-color is set. if i unset it i see my running animation. i also have mouseenter mouseleave listeners, which change the background color of that element. so if my animation class is running and i set my background-color through this listeners it stops. in all other browsers the animation is still running(( looks like property overrieds the same property in the animation.(( only in chrome.

Comment: That makes a little more sense @user3680648 - now can you code it up into Pen ?

Comment: **Actually the answer is not entirely correct**...... Chrome 43 will handle both -webkit-animation and animation BUT and a big BUT only one at a time! basically they do If listner do something else legacylistener do that....  So if somewhere you are calling animation end and expecting non webkit sites to not be affected surprise chrome will handle it now.

Answer (score -1):

ok, the point was -- the animation gets covered by another class having background-color. But ist still interesting why it happend suddenly, and why it still works in other browsers